# In Wordpress can I store a JSON object as a post and retrieve as it through REST?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-json-api

Is it possible in WP to paste in a post a JSON object such as

```js
[
  {
    name: 'hello',
    type: 'myself',
  },
]
```

**and retrieve it exactly like this?**

The maximum I've been able to do is to add this in a `code` block and then I will get

```
\n<pre class=\"wp-block-code\"><code> [{\"name\":\"hello\",\"type\":\"myself\",
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if the string is obtained through a variable with `content="..."`, everything there has to have the `"` escaped, so I don't delete the question but it was a nonsense question